# Add Groupings to DF for Closing Stock Prices

Tags: r

I'm creating a hypothetical scenario, where I trade a single stock based on whether the closing price is up or down.  If a stock closes lower then it closed the previous day, I want to add a 'S' (for sell) and if it closes higher than it closed the previous day, I want to add a 'B'.  So, I want to add these S and B tags and then calculate the difference, which is the daily profit.

Here is the code that I'm testing.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(quantmod)
library(zoo)

# enter tickers to download time-series data
e <- new.env()
getSymbols("SBUX", env = e)
pframe <- do.call(merge, as.list(e))
#head(pframe)


# get a subset of data
df = pframe$SBUX.Close

colnames(df)[1] <- "Close"
head(df)

# Assign groupings
addGrps <- df %>% mutate(Group = ifelse(Close < lead(Close), "S", "B"))

# create subsets
buys <- filter(addGrps, Group == "B")
sells <- filter(addGrps, Group == "S")


# find daily differences
dt2 <- df %>%
mutate(Diff = Close - lead(Close))

# get up and down price movements
ups <- filter(df2, Diff > 0 )
downs <- filter(df2, Diff <= 0 )

# cumulative sums of longs and shorts
longs<-cumsum(ups$Diff)
shorts<-cumsum(downs$Diff)
```

Everything before 'addGrps' works fine.  When I get to the 'addGrps' line, I get this error: 'Error in UseMethod("mutate_") :
no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "c('xts', 'zoo')"'

This is just a hypothetical example of optimizing trades, if somehow you know at the beginning of the day what a stock will close at.  Obviously it's impossible.  I'm just trying to get this concept working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mutate and filter will not work for zoo.
Instead use:

```
# Assign groupings
transform(df,Group = ifelse(Close < lead(Close), "S", "B"))
# create subsets
buys <- addGrps[addGrps$Group == "B"]
sells <- addGrps[addGrps$Group == "S"]


# find daily differences
df2 <- transform(df,Diff = Close - lead(Close))

# get up and down price movements
ups <- df2[df2$Diff > 0]
downs <- df2[df2$Diff <= 0]

# cumulative sums of longs and shorts
longs<-cumsum(ups$Diff)
shorts<-cumsum(downs$Diff)
```